# Changing Pine Script linear regression time frame to 10D

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to change the linear regression built in indicator to use a 10D time frame with 1M candles. I have tried to find a similar community indicator but have had no luck. I know this is possible in TOS but am trying to convert to tradingview.

In the screenshot you can see the built in linear regression channel on the right, however I would like it to look more like the yellow lines I have drawn on the chart. Any help would be appreciated.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible with the built-in indicator.

You can either try to write your own, or there are some open source linear regression indicators in community scripts. You can find one that you like and modify the source with `security()` calls so that it requests data from 10D timeframe.